# In phpmyadmin how to add fields to the top instead of the bottom?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am wondering if its possible to add fields **to the top** of the table instead at the end.

So that when I do a query, its always getting the most recent fields and that the *id( 1 )* is always at the end of the table and the most recent id is always at the top of page 1 of the results.

Comment: It is all about the sorting. phpMyAdmin shows the query result and the query itself should be properly sorted `ORDER BY id DESC`, as @Barmar mentioned, to get the representation you need. For your needs `ORDER` section mentioned above should be simply added to the end of your query.

Comment: I tried doing the request like this, but its not pulling anything tho  $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'" ORDER BY id DESC)or die( mysqli_error($con));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '.$userid.' ORDER BY id DESC'; // should help you.
$result = mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: @Clarklight And without `ORDER BY` everything is Ok?

Comment: I think i have got it!! THanks I retried it $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'" ORDER BY id DESC)or die( mysqli_error($con)); and for some reason now it works

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're actually asking about rows, not fields.

If you want the results of a query to come in a specific order, use the `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` query. So if you want the highest ID first, use `ORDER BY id DESC`.

When you don't use `ORDER BY`, the results can be in any aribtrary order.

Comment: Like this? $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'" ORDER BY id DESC)or die( mysqli_error($con));

Comment: Except for the missing doublequote at the end, I don't see why it shouldn't work.